# IIS zero down time site set up is still randomly sending requests to the server that is set to unhealthy

Tags: iis, arr, server-farm

We have a blue, green site and server farm set up for zero downtime deployment which works fine but we are seeing in the web logs for the site that does the routing that every now and then the wrong server is being sent requests.

```
2023-02-19 09:50:05 /DocumentView DID=23932&SERVER-ROUTED=LIVE-GREEN
2023-02-19 09:50:09 /FileDownload FID=50516&SERVER-ROUTED=LIVE-BLUE
2023-02-19 09:50:13 /Publish DocID=9154358&SERVER-ROUTED=LIVE-BLUE
2023-02-19 09:50:15 /SiteView DID=23932&SERVER-ROUTED=LIVE-GREEN
```

In this instance it tries to send two requests to Live-Blue which is set to Unhealthy and the site Stopped. The Health Test interval is set to 1 seconds (at the moment).

It's not happening a lot(maybe once every 25k request) but is very annoying to those that do get the 502 error message. (502.3 - Bad Gateway: Forwarder Connection Error (ARR).)

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix or diagnose the issue?

Comment: I've just found out that we are also getting a intermittent 404's on the redirecting site even though our global URL rewrite rule should have passed the request onto the server-farm. So a similar issue?! The ARR stops working correctly resulting in either a 502 couldn't route to the stopped site or a 404 couldn't find the path because the rewrite rule didn't kick in.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr) to view detailed error information, If not enough information is available, you can also debug the cause using [IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @samwu Thanks. I've had this running but it doesn't tell me why it chose to send the request to the wrong server it just shows that it did. It also doesn't show why it intermittently ignores the rewrite rule.

Comment: Have you analyzed your dump file?